# Sorting bibliography entries of similar author (First author) and year in apa-good style

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style, sorting

I need to sort my bibliography (apa-good style) by only the first author (A) and year of the paper. Example:
A, R, T, N, T (2016) Extraction..
A, G, T (2015) Analysis...

But now the result is:
A, G, T (2015) Analysis...
A, R, T, N, T (2016) Extraction...

I have all this bibliography in a file D.bib.

The main document in TeX:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{apa-good}
\bibliography{D.bib}
\end{document}
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: There seems to be more than one version of the `apa-good` style floating around on the Internet. Could you provide a source/website for the version you're using?